# Is the natural metric on an irreducible compact symmetric space Einstein?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

Let $ G/K $ be an irreducible compact symmetric space. Let $ g $ be the pushforward onto $ G/K $ of the biinvariant metric on $ G $. Is $ g $ an Einstein metric on $ G/K $?

This is true for $ S^n=SO_{n+1}/SO_n $ where $ g $ the round metric is an Einstein metric.

It is also true for $ \mathbb{C}P^n=SU_{n+1}/SU_n $ where $ g $ the Fubini-Study metric is an Einstein metric.

Fleshing out the answer given by Johnny Lemmon:

Theorem 7.44 states: Let $ M=G/K $ be a $ G $-homogeneous isotropy irreducible space. Then (up to homotheties) $ M $ admits a unique $ G $-invariant Riemannian metric. This Riemannian metric is Einstein.

Example 7.45 of the same reference states that every irreducible symmetric space is isotropy irreducible.

Since the natural metric on $ G/K $ is $ G $ invariant then by Theorem 7.44 it is the unique $ G $ invariant metric on $ G/K $ up to homotheties and moreover it is Einstein.

Thus Thm 7.44 shows that the answer to the original question is "yes" and moreover the natural metric on any isotropy irreducible compact space $ G/K $ is Einstein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Theorem 7.44 in the book "Einstein manifolds" by Besse, for the case of isotropy irreducible spaces. In general, it seems that this is not true, but you should find Theorem 7.99 (ibid.) useful.

Comment: I fleshed out your answer a bit more and added that as an update to my question. Did I interpret what you said correctly? Also does this all hold for noncompact symmetric spaces as well?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira yes, thank you for taking the time to write out in more detail my remark - I now realize it was rather brief and poorly worded. What I meant is that the irreducibility hypothesis is really necessary, and Thm 7.99 (but rather, section H, tables $7$ and $8$) lists some cases when the standard metric on $G/H$ is Einstein, but the space is not isotropy irreducible. So yes, what you wrote in your answer is correct. And yes, it also holds for noncompact irreducible symmetric spaces (again by Example 7.45).